# Qual a diferença entre as propriedades Height e ClientHeight de um TForm?

Tags: delphi, layout, gui

No Delphi um Formulário possui 2 propriedades para definir a altura do mesmo: **Height** e **ClientHeight**.
Porém, qual a diferença entre as propriedades **Height** e **ClientHeight** de um TForm?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Height** é a própria altura do formulário. Ela conta por exemplo a barra de títulos e as bordas superiores e inferiores.

**ClientHeight** é a altura disponível para componentes filhos do formulário.

Por exemplo: se a altura de um formulário modal for limitada ao tamanho *ClientHeight* do formulário principal, e este formulário modal estiver verticalmente alinhado no centro do formulário principal, você ainda poderá ver a barra de títulos do formulário principal por tráz do formulário modal.

Você pode setar *ClientHeight* para determinar o quanto quer de espaço útil para os componentes filhos, mas o uso mais comum é **ler** esta propriedade para delimitar o tamanho dos componentes filhos ou o tamanho de formulários modais.